# Aggregate functions with NULL not behaving as expected

Tags: sql, sqlite

With SQLite, I'm attempting a simple `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(100, NULL);
```

This returns `null`.  Shouldn't it be `100` instead?

According to the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

> Aggregate max() returns NULL if and only if there are no non-NULL values in the group.

`100` is a non-null value, so I would not expect to get `null` returned from `MAX()` in this case.  Am I misunderstanding the documentation?  And, how can I use `MAX()`, by either ignoring `null` values in the set, or by treating them as zero `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the aggregate version.

From [the right documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc):

> The multi-argument max() function returns the argument with the maximum value, or return NULL if any argument is NULL.

and

> Note that max() is a simple function when it has 2 or more arguments but operates as an aggregate function if given only a single argument.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!  Thanks again!  Any thoughts on treating `NULL` like `0`?  I think there's some SQL ternary, right?  I'm a bit rusty... looking that up now.

Comment: Nevermind, just got it fixed with `IFNULL()`.  Thanks again!